# Pause execution of onItemSelected of spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

How could i stop the onItemSelected Event for a spinner when i use **setSelection(position).**

I'm looking for a clean solution.

Thanks

Comment: If this all happens in the same class, you can set a flag in `setSelection()` and then check the flag in `onItemSelected()`.

Comment: i need to disable & enable the spinner event : onItemSelected() several times.
 i have two spinner which use the same main function.